# Append class to control that is using Skin

Tags: asp.net

- I have a Button control, and default skin for Button controls.
- That default skin has CssClass defined.

However on one page, I have a set of buttons in one column, and I need to acces these buttons with selector. Obvious way to do it is to use class. However CssClass property from skin overrides CssClass (or class attribute) defined on control.

Is there any way to address this issue?

Comment: Is this button placed in some data-drivern control?

Comment: it's created inside GridView/Column ItemTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Click Me" SkinID="ButtonSkin" CssClass='<%# Button1.CssClass + " anotherClass" %>' />`